# Centos Virtual host loading default page

Tags: centos, virtualhost

I have asked a question which was related to this but not same,

I have a centos VPS, which has two wordpress websites,
one is mbas.co.in and another is onlinemba123.com, now for virtual hosting using just **ONE IP ADDRESS**, first I started mbas.co.in, which is working fine, when I added onlinemba123.com then, it is loading default Centos page instead of my website, and I am just testing my onlinemba123 website, I haven't configured DNS for it, I am testing it through editing my PC's hosts file,

My website folder names are also same as in the conf file below

Now my question is how can I load my website instead of Default page, is my virtual host config fine?

My virtual host config:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.mbas.co.in
    ServerName mbas.co.in
    ErrorLog logs/mbas.co.in-error_log
    CustomLog logs/mbas.co.in-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.onlinemba123.com
    ServerName www.onlinemba123.com
    ErrorLog logs/onlinemba123-error_log
    CustomLog logs/onlinemba123-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

My computers host file is:

```
xx.xxx.xxx.xxx  www.onlinemba123.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an index file in the document root for the virtual host(s) in question.

Comment: index file? You mean the index file which is inside that wordpress(onlinemba123) folder?

Comment: One of the filenames given in the `DirectoryIndex` directive.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams I am still not getting which Index File, sorry for been a jerk but I am learning something new

Comment: Try putting a file called `index.html` or `index.php` in place.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams OK I inserted one inex.html file into folder www.onlinemba123.com and when I checked it, then I am getting that index.html instead of Centos Default page,
So it means that my wordpress is having problems, am I rite?

Comment: Dunno. But it's not picking up the WP index page.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams No I fixed it, actually their was no index.php file inside, now I added and my site started,
Really thanks for that, I appreciate your help, It was actually my wordpress problem, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Just add index.php or index.html(depend upon the priority order) the  file in the document root for the virtual host mentioned in question. For PHP based website its should work.

Comment: Thanks, but this does appear to be the same answer that was accepted 3 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe your Apache is not rightly set up for working with php. Put a file named index.php and in there put `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. If you see this line right this way then your apache needs to be configured to work with php, else if you see a phpinfo page - something like a page with a blue bar at the top - then your apache is ok to php, so there´s something wrong with your wordpress files. See the index.php file from it. Success for you.